# Will setting MySQL root password prevent it from autostarting?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

I installed and set up MySQL on Snow Leopard, and created a Launch Deamon to start MySQL automatically (Got it from [this tutorial](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/)). But the step to verify that it is working, doesn't work for me:

```
mysql -uroot
```

That is because I have to log in with a password:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Will this be a problem when it tries to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The daemon ( server ) is completely separate from what you're trying to run, which is the client.  It's like the difference between a web server and a browser.  The server can run all day long and not care whether you've got a browser running or not.

I don't know how Mac init scripts run, but if mysqld (note the 'd' suffix) is ever running at all, it should continue to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be. Given I've never set up mysql on a mac but there isn't any reason for it to request a password to start a daemon. mysql daemeons start without passwords on unix and windows servers all the time. If it does... find a different tutorial because that one is doing it wrong, imo.

Answer (score 0):

The password you mentioned is just needed to access the server, but not to start it. You server should start without any problems if you did install it correctly. Normally I just download the binary from mysql.com and install it. No configuration needed.